# How to get last id inserted. mysql_insert_id() not working

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, opencart

I am working in opencart version 2x. I am trying to get the last id of row inserted.This code working for 1.5x version but returning nothing in 2x

My code:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO `" . DB_PREFIX . "endicia_label_info`  SET order_id  = '$orderID',postage_balance = '$postage_balance',file_name='$fileName',dte_created_date_time = NOW(),tracking_no='$tracking_no',final_postage = '$final_postage',mail_type='$Mailtype',mail_class='$ClassMail',label_size='$labelimgsize',label_pieces='$labelpieces',labelname='$labelname',Status='$Status'");
$label_id = mysql_insert_id();
return $label_id;
```

Comment: try this $this->db->getLastId();

Comment: try select id from table order by id desc limit 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use this in **[OpenCart](http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=method_db_getlastid)** for getting last insert id:

```
$this->db->getLastId()
```

[**From OpenCart User Guide:**](http://wiki.opencarthelp.com/doku.php?id=method_db_getlastid)

**Method Reference / DB::getLastId():** Returns the ID generated for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the previous query.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this method `$this->db->getLastId()`;

Answer (score 1):

`$this->db->getLastId();` this function is used to get last inserted id

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```